# Is there a way to make custom url destination based on source in vercel rewrites?

Tags: javascript, proxy, reverse-proxy, vercel, astrojs

My goal is to extract URL from the pathname and then use that URL as a destination in vercel rewrites to make a proxy

let's say if a user try to open `example.com/google.com/search?q=hello` then it should rewrite to `google.com/search?q=hello`

In code I am trying to define like this

```
"rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/proxy/:path*",
      "destination": "https://:path*"
    }
  ]
```

But the thing is that Its appending `\*` at the end of destination link which is throwing some error.